# Error en función spread en R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Cuando intento utilizar  `spread(instrumento, precio)` me devuelve un error 
 `Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 851 rows` Necesito trabajar con los diferentes instrumentos, para ello lo intento llevar como variables

```
         fecha instrumento precio
2   2020-04-20      YPFD   397.50
3   2020-04-20      YPFD   397.50
4   2020-04-20      YPFD   397.50
5   2020-04-17      YPFD   401.85
6   2020-04-17      YPFD   402.00
7   2020-04-17      YPFD   401.00
8   2020-04-16      YPFD   400.60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por empezar, con los datos que muestras, no tiene sentido hacer un `spread()`, por lo que entiendo, lo que buscas, es que cada fila sea una fecha y cada columna un instrumento, sin embargo tiene múltiples precios para un mismo instrumento/fecha y la condición para poder hacer un `spread` es que exista un único valor por fila/columna, en tu caso fecha/instrumento. Se me ocurre que lo que necesitas en primer lugar es alguna función de agregación, por ejemplo:

```
library("tidyverse")

read.table(text="fecha instrumento precio
2020-04-20      YPFD   397.50
2020-04-20      YPFD   397.50
2020-04-20      YPFD   397.50
2020-04-17      YPFD   401.85
2020-04-17      YPFD   402.00
2020-04-17      YPFD   401.00
2020-04-16      YPFD   400.60", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(fecha, instrumento) %>% 
  summarize(precio=max(precio)) %>% 
  spread(instrumento, precio) 


# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   fecha [3]
  fecha       YPFD
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 2020-04-16  401.
2 2020-04-17  402 
3 2020-04-20  398.
```